# Xojo crashes when selecting page setup or print from file menue

Tags: crash, xojo

I'm new to both Linux and Xojo. I have been very impressed with Xojo until now. I'm running it on Linux Mint, 20.2 64 bit. Same error on Xojo 2.1, 3.0, and 3.1. On a clean install of Linux and Xojo, Xojo crashes if I simply go to File/Print or File/Page setup. I've reinstalled Linux and Xojo numerous times on two different computers with same results. What could be causing this to happen? It's such a basic function it must be something on my system but I have no idea how to resolve it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There is unfortunately a known issue with Xojo and Print Setup dialogs on Linux. There is nothing you can do, it is a framework level problem.

More details about the known issue are available on their bug tracker system:
[#58365 - Linux/Pi: Printing crashes or fails to present print dialog](https://tracker.xojo.com/xojoinc/xojo/-/issues/58365)